# Subsetting a vector with undefined columns

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors with varying lengths.
The first column has an integer representing an index within the vector where I need to subset the vector.

```
v1 <- c(6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
v2 <- c(5,1,2,3,4,5)
v3 <- c(3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
```

I need to subset the two positions surrounding the index value on either side, including the index position. 
For example, in the first vector, the index is 6 so I need the 4th-8th positions.

The issue comes when the index is too close to an end of the vector and I get an "undefined columns selected" error. I would like to subset all the vectors in the list and put them in a single data frame with undefined columns replaced by NA's so that it will look like this:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
   3  4  5  6  7
   2  3  4  5 NA
  NA  1  2  3  4
```

The overall goal is to do various summary statistics on the columns and missing values are ok.

EDIT:

The first element of each vector is not part of the data I am trying to manipulate. It is just an index that tells me where to subset the data in the rest of the vector.

The first element is never a 1. The lowest it can be is 2 and the highest is dependent on the length of the vectors. Here is some further examples using the same data, but changing the first element to show how that would affect the subsetting.

```
x1 <- c(2,1,2,3,4,5)

X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
NA NA  1  2  3

x2 <- c(3,1,2,3,4,5)

X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
NA  1  2  3  4

x3 <- c(4,1,2,3,4,5)

X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
 1  2  3  4  5

x4 <- c(5,1,2,3,4,5)

X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
 2  3  4  5 NA

x5 <- c(6,1,2,3,4,5)

X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
 3  4  5 NA NA
```

Comment: your output matrix seems to be different from what you explain. For ex: the first one, shouldn't it be 4:8?

Comment: The first number represents the position in the vector I need to subset, not the number I need to subset. v1[6] is the 5 in v1.

Comment: Can the first value be 1 then? I ask because the last row's first element is NA for your case. So it clearly is nota desired value. So, if the first column is 1, then it should be NA,NA,NA,1,2 (for the last row)? I find it ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist <- list(v1 <- c(6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
               v2 <- c(5,1,2,3,4,5),
               v3 <- c(3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13))

res <- sapply(mylist,function(x) {
  ind <- max(2,x[1]-2):min(length(x),x[1]+2)
  res <- rep(NA,5)
  res[ind-x[1]+3] <- x[ind]
  res
})

t(res)

#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    3    4    5    6    7
# [2,]    2    3    4    5   NA
# [3,]   NA    1    2    3    4
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I was getting hung up on replacing undefined columns with NA's, but I like the idea of replacing a vector of NA's with the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
t( sapply(list(v1,v2,v3), function(v) v[ (v[1]-2):(v[1]+2) ] ) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    4    5    6    7
[2,]    2    3    4    5   NA
[3,]    3    1    2    3    4
```

I think you do have a problem with describing task because the NA in your third row does not fit with the description, especially so after your comment. If you change the problem so that you would reasonably get the third row as illustrated( currently incorrectly), then you need to pad the vector with left NA's:

```
v1 <- c(6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
v2 <- c(5,1,2,3,4,5)
v3 <- c(2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
t( sapply(list(v1,v2,v3), function(v) c( rep(NA, max(0,3-v[1])), v[ (v[1]-2):(v[1]+2) ] ) ) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    4    5    6    7
[2,]    2    3    4    5   NA
[3,]   NA    2    1    2    3
```

Comment: I think the last row's first element should be an NA.

Comment: From what the OP has shown. But I agree there's some ambiguity.

Comment: I think OP wants this modification of your answer: `t(sapply(list(v1,v2,v3), function(v) c(NA,NA,NA,v[-1])[v[1]:(v[1]+4)]))`

Comment: I don't the OP really know what he wants. Either the first row was wrong or the last row and the comment clarified that the first row was correct, so the last row must be wrong.

Comment: All of the examples were correct. I have added some more to help with the explanation of the problem.

Comment: Correct? ... Perhaps by your hidden, undisclosed rule set. Downvoting for wasting our time.

Comment: Oh no! My internet points!
Fortunately, I received some help that solved the problem. Thanks for the effort.